# IEquityComparer to '=' overloader

Tags: vb.net

My question is for my general understanding, it is not a problem, following are demo classes from my project:

```
    Public Class Registration
        Inherits HumanBase

        Private _NameeValue As HumanName
        Property Namee As HumanName
            Get
                Return _NameeValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As HumanName)
                If Not _NameeValue = Value Then
                    _NameeValue = Value
                    OnPropertyChanged("Namee")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _UserPasswordValue As String
        Public Property UserPassword() As String
            Get
                Return _UserPasswordValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If Not _UserPasswordValue.Equals(value) Then
                    _UserPasswordValue = value
                    OnPropertyChanged("UserPassword")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _UserEmailValue As String
        Public Property UserEmail() As String
            Get
                Return _UserEmailValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If Not _UserEmailValue = value Then
                    _UserEmailValue = value
                    OnPropertyChanged("UserEmail")
                End If

            End Set
        End Property

        Property UserPassword2 As String
    End Class
Public Class HumanName
        Inherits HumanBase
        Implements IComparable(Of HumanName)
        Implements IEqualityComparer(Of HumanName)



#Region "Private Variables"
        Private _TitleNameValue As CommonTypes.TitleName
        Private _FirstNameValue As String
        Private _MiddleNameValue As String
        Private _LastNameValue As String
        Private _SuffixNameValue As CommonTypes.Suffixname
#End Region

#Region "Property Variables"
        Property TitleName As CommonTypes.TitleName
            Get
                Return _TitleNameValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As CommonTypes.TitleName)
                If Not _TitleNameValue = Value Then
                    _TitleNameValue = Value
                    OnPropertyChanged("TitleName")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Property FirstName As String
            Get
                Return _FirstNameValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                If Not _FirstNameValue = Value Then
                    _FirstNameValue = Value
                    OnPropertyChanged("FirstName")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Property MiddleName As String
            Get
                Return _MiddleNameValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                If Not _MiddleNameValue = Value Then
                    _MiddleNameValue = Value
                    OnPropertyChanged("MiddleName")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Property LastName As String
            Get
                Return _LastNameValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                If Not _LastNameValue = Value Then
                    _LastNameValue = Value
                    OnPropertyChanged("LastName")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Property SuffixName As CommonTypes.Suffixname
            Get
                Return _SuffixNameValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As CommonTypes.Suffixname)
                If Not _SuffixNameValue = Value Then
                    _SuffixNameValue = Value
                    OnPropertyChanged("SuffixName")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
#End Region

        Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As HumanName) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of HumanName).CompareTo
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Function Equals1(ByVal x As HumanName, ByVal y As HumanName) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of HumanName).Equals
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Function GetHashCode1(ByVal obj As HumanName) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of HumanName).GetHashCode
            Return True
        End Function
    End Class
```

The code errors out at coding time itself at "`If Not _NameeValue = Value Then`" and the error is `Error    Operator '=' is not defined for types 'SharesCommCodeLib.Human.HumanName' and 'SharesCommCodeLib.Human.HumanName'`.

Could you please tell me why '=" is not working when I implemented both ICOMPAREABLE and IEquitableComparer. Would DotNet does not consider it for Operator Overloading.

Thank you.

Comment: Try overloading the = operator.

Comment: Thank you, but can't IEqualComparer does not work for '=' operator overloading, the verbal/dictionary meaning satisfies them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. i strongly recommend to set [`OPTION STRICT` to ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), your code wouldn't even compile when you try to return a `Boolean` from a method which signature defines an `Integer` as return type. That helps to avoid errors
2. The `IEqualityComparer` Interface is used to define your own definition of equality and can be used wherever this interface is used to specify equality, for example in the constructors of `Hashtable`, `NameValueCollection` or `OrderedDictionary`
3. If you want to use the `=` operator on custom types you need to [**overload it**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379613%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

---

```
Public Shared Operator =(ByVal humanName1 As HumanName, ByVal humanName2 As HumanName) As Boolean
    Return humanName1._FirstNameValue.Equals(humanName2._FirstNameValue) AndAlso _
        humanName1._MiddleNameValue.Equals(humanName2._MiddleNameValue) AndAlso _
        humanName1._LastNameValue.Equals(humanName2._LastNameValue)
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal humanName1 As HumanName, ByVal humanName2 As HumanName) As Boolean
    Return Not humanName1 = humanName2
End Operator
```

Comment: or just `return humanName1._FirstNameValue.Equals(humanName2._FirstNameValue) AndAlso _        humanName1._MiddleNameValue.Equals(humanName2._MiddleNameValue) AndAlso _        humanName1._LastNameValue.Equals(humanName2._LastNameValue)`

Comment: Thank you.  For the <> operator I used the following code: `Return Not (humanName1 = humanName2)` but why cant the _EqualComparer does not satisfy this comparision.

Comment: @surpavan: edited my answer to provide more informations on your interface and for what it is used. If you want to use the `=` operator for equality-comparison(instead of reference-comparison coming from `Object.Equals`) you need to overload the operator itself as shown above.

Comment: Thank you, so I understand that Dot Net Names or interfaces are build to make sure they are called with same names withing the .net architecture.